# Replicate subset of tables from AWS RDS mysql to another RDS/external mysql instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, replication, subset, rds

The MySQL database that I am using is in an Amazon AWS RDS 5.6. Only 1 of the tables needs to be replicated.  The slave can be another AWS RDS MySQL instance.  Read replica tables replicates the entire database.

Can what I am describing be done manually or through other means?

Comment: General grammar editing to make the thoughts flow a bit better and I pulled your question out so that it's clear where the question itself is.  This can be very helpful for people who are interested in assisting you but don't have the patience to read everything that you've written.

Comment: do you need the data to be synced in (near) real time? In these tables do the data get inserted only or updated as well? If the latter, is there a column storing the last_update timestamp? These questions will help determine your replication options.

Answer (score 2):

On RDS MySQL Engine the replication ignore/do table/db options cannot be set. You could create a read replica, set read_only of the read replica to 0 and change the tables you dont need on the slave to BLACKHOLE.

You could also install you own mysql on a EC2 instance where you would have control over all options.